# Sending a pointer over a socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers

I have a C++ client/server set up and I need to transfer a pointer (specifically, `uint8_t*`) between them.

EDIT: the buffer that the pointer points to

Using the traditional `send/recv` does not appear to work (requires a `char*`), and ideally I would send this pointer as part of a packet with some other variables.

What is the best way of doing this?

Server side to illustrate:

```
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    int iResult = recv( this->ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0 );
    if( iResult > 0 )
    {
        // ideally recvbuf would contain the pointer
        // Do some stuff

        // Send the buffer back to the sender
        std::string result = "Message received";
        // ideally here I would be sending my pointer, not this string
        int iSendResult = send( this->ClientSocket, result.c_str(), (int)strlen( result.c_str() ), 0 );
        if( iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            printf( "send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError() );
            closesocket( this->ClientSocket );
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Wait, do you want to send the *pointer address* or a buffer that’s pointed to by the pointer?

Comment: Why? Isn't it going to be unreadable at the source anyway?

Comment: You want to send the data the pointer points to, not the pointer itself.  sending an address from one machine to another isn't going to get you anything as all OS'es randomize the process address space.

Comment: You cannot reasonably send a pointer over a socket because the pointer value doesn't mean anything on the target machine. Obviously you can send whatever the pointer is pointing to, is that what you want?

Comment: What do you imagine that the receiving program would be able to use that pointer for?

Comment: Just cast to char*